# How can I use AJAX to dynamically change span text in this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**LOGIC DEMO** (jsFiddle): **[Click Here!](http://jsfiddle.net/alpha1337/NMDSG/)**

The demo linked above is the result I would like to achieve. However, I need to translate this to dynamically fill this content from XML variables *asize* & *aprice*. Below is the current method I am using for cascading dropdowns using AJAX.

**XML DATA:**

```
<avar aval="1" asize="Small Flag" aprice="$26.00" atext="Size 0"/>
```

**JS DATA:**

```
if($('#drpType').val() == "1")
  {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Flags.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
    $(xml).find('avar').each(function(){
    $('#drpSize').append($('<option></option>').val($(this).attr('aval')).html($(this).attr('atext')));
        });
    }
  }); 
}
```

**LOGIC (Non-Functional):**

```
if($('#drpSize').val() == "1")
  {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Flags.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
    // GET XML Value (asize) & print to <span class="ms"> onChange (#drpSize)
    // GET XML Value (aprice) & print to <span class="mp"> onChange (#drpSize)
    $('#drpSize').change(function (){
    $(xml).find('aval').each(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "1") {
    $('.ms').text('asize');
    $('.mp').text('aprice');
        });
    }
  }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the xml into a traversable xmldoc before you can use find.

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
$(xmlDoc).find(...
```